# Logical breakdown for dot net namespace hierarchy

Tags: .net

I am looking for a reference/links that give good high level logical breakdown of the dot net namespace.

And if it has some indicators to individual frameworks like what's specific to asp.net, wcf, wpf, wwf etc.

Any links/references/diagrams are highly appreciated.

### Update

[I found one poster for .net 4.0](http://brad_abrams.members.winisp.net/Projects/PDC2008/PDC2008-NETFX4.pdf).

Comment: Not sure your question is clear enough.  Are you just looking to find the *contents* of the system namespaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/a/3/4a3c7c55-84ab-4588-84a4-f96424a7d82d/NET35_Namespaces_Poster_LORES.pdf

Answer (score 0):

[The MSDN Library documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0x726c2.aspx) should be a good start; it contains the entire framework and you can drill down into it as far as you would like to go.

Note: [the first link on the page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229335.aspx) contains all of the class definitions.